# Show part of the legend in ggplot2 when using several geom_path (different dataframes)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am building a Campbell diagram for a turbine. I need to plot "basic" lines equivalent to the rotational frequencies (1P,2P, 3P, etc..) and then I want plot to calculated frequencies of my turbine.

For clarity sake, I need my rotational frequencies to be red and black and the calculated ones of another colour, and (that is the tricky part) : **I do not want the red/black curves to appear in the legend, only the other colours**. I have my data in different dataframes (rotational frequencies and calculated ones) so I am calling `geom_path` twice. I did try to use `show.legend = FALSE` on the `geom_path` where the natural frequencies are called, but it did not work.

Below is my data and code:

```
> dput(df_Pmodes)
structure(list(RPM = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 
14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 
12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 
10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 
8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 
8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 
4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 
15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17), Pmodes = c(0, 0.0333333333333333, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.1, 0.135833333333333, 0.136666666666667, 0.149166666666667, 
0.181, 0.214333333333333, 0.2405, 0.250666666666667, 0.2525, 
0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 
0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 
0.252833333333333, 0.252833333333333, 0, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.133333333333333, 0.2, 0.271666666666667, 0.273333333333333, 
0.298333333333333, 0.362, 0.428666666666667, 0.481, 0.501333333333333, 
0.505, 0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 
0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 
0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 0.505666666666667, 0, 0.1, 
0.2, 0.3, 0.4075, 0.41, 0.4475, 0.543, 0.643, 0.7215, 0.752, 
0.7575, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585, 
0.7585, 0.7585, 0.7585, 0, 0.133333333333333, 0.266666666666667, 
0.4, 0.543333333333333, 0.546666666666667, 0.596666666666667, 
0.724, 0.857333333333333, 0.962, 1.00266666666667, 1.01, 1.01133333333333, 
1.01133333333333, 1.01133333333333, 1.01133333333333, 1.01133333333333, 
1.01133333333333, 1.01133333333333, 1.01133333333333, 1.01133333333333, 
1.01133333333333, 0, 0.166666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 
0.679166666666667, 0.683333333333333, 0.745833333333333, 0.905, 
1.07166666666667, 1.2025, 1.25333333333333, 1.2625, 1.26416666666667, 
1.26416666666667, 1.26416666666667, 1.26416666666667, 1.26416666666667, 
1.26416666666667, 1.26416666666667, 1.26416666666667, 1.26416666666667, 
1.26416666666667, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.815, 0.82, 0.895, 1.086, 
1.286, 1.443, 1.504, 1.515, 1.517, 1.517, 1.517, 1.517, 1.517, 
1.517, 1.517, 1.517, 1.517, 1.517, 0, 0.233333333333333, 0.466666666666667, 
0.7, 0.950833333333333, 0.956666666666667, 1.04416666666667, 
1.267, 1.50033333333333, 1.6835, 1.75466666666667, 1.7675, 1.76983333333333, 
1.76983333333333, 1.76983333333333, 1.76983333333333, 1.76983333333333, 
1.76983333333333, 1.76983333333333, 1.76983333333333, 1.76983333333333, 
1.76983333333333, 0, 0.266666666666667, 0.533333333333333, 0.8, 
1.08666666666667, 1.09333333333333, 1.19333333333333, 1.448, 
1.71466666666667, 1.924, 2.00533333333333, 2.02, 2.02266666666667, 
2.02266666666667, 2.02266666666667, 2.02266666666667, 2.02266666666667, 
2.02266666666667, 2.02266666666667, 2.02266666666667, 2.02266666666667, 
2.02266666666667), Pnames = c("1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", 
"1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", 
"1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "1P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", 
"2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", 
"2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "2P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", 
"3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", 
"3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "3P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", 
"4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", 
"4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "4P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", 
"5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", 
"5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "5P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", 
"6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", 
"6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "6P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", 
"7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", 
"7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "7P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", 
"8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", 
"8P", "8P", "8P", "8P", "8P")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-176L))
> dput(df_turbine_modes)
structure(list(RPM = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 
14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 
12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 
10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 
8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 4, 6, 
8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 0, 2, 
4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 15.17, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
0, 2, 4, 6, 8.15, 8.2, 8.95, 10.86, 12.86, 14.43, 15.04, 15.15, 
15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 15.17, 
15.17), modes = c(0.842, 0.867, 0.932, 1.013, 1.098, 1.133, 1.202, 
1.256, 1.297, 1.33, 1.365, 1.417, 1.252, 1.161, 1.115, 1.083, 
1.059, 1.04, 1.023, 1.009, 0.996, 0.984, 1.322, 1.322, 1.322, 
1.32, 1.316, 1.316, 1.314, 1.306, 1.294, 1.28, 1.273, 1.271, 
1.274, 1.277, 1.28, 1.282, 1.284, 1.286, 1.288, 1.29, 1.291, 
1.293, 2.016, 2.05, 2.147, 2.291, 2.479, 2.58, 2.818, 3.028, 
3.221, 3.417, 3.679, 4.262, 2.977, 2.649, 2.526, 2.451, 2.4, 
2.361, 2.33, 2.304, 2.281, 2.261, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 
0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 
0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 0.875, 
1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 
1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 1.01, 
3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 
3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 
3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 3.826, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 
4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 
4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556, 4.556), names = c("Blade 1st Flap", 
"Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", 
"Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", 
"Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", 
"Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", 
"Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Flap", 
"Blade 1st Flap", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", 
"Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", 
"Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", 
"Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", 
"Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", 
"Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 1st Edge", "Blade 2nd Flap", 
"Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", 
"Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", 
"Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", 
"Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", 
"Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", "Blade 2nd Flap", 
"Blade 2nd Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", 
"Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", 
"Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", 
"Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", 
"Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", 
"Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Flap", "Tower 1st Edge", 
"Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", 
"Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", 
"Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", 
"Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", 
"Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 1st Edge", 
"Tower 1st Edge", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", 
"Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", 
"Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", 
"Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", 
"Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", 
"Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Flap", "Tower 2nd Edge", 
"Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", 
"Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", 
"Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", 
"Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", 
"Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", "Tower 2nd Edge", 
"Tower 2nd Edge")), row.names = c(NA, -154L), class = "data.frame")

df_operating_range = data.frame(RPM = c(8,15), freq = c(0,5))

default_colour = c("red","black","red",rep("black",2),"red",rep("black",2),'#4363d8',"#ffa500", '#46f0f0')
ggplot(df_Pmodes,aes(RPM,Pmodes, col = Pnames))+
  geom_path(size = 2)+
  geom_point(size = 3)+
  geom_path(data =df_turbine_modes,aes(RPM,modes,col = names), size = 2)+
  geom_point(data =df_turbine_modes,aes(RPM,modes,col = names), size = 3)+
  geom_ribbon(data  = df_operating_range, aes(x = RPM , ymin = 0, ymax = 5),
            alpha = 0.3,show.legend = FALSE,linetype=1,inherit.aes = F) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "",values = default_colour)+
  annotate("text", x = rep(max(RPM),8), y = mode_label_y, label = mode_text,hjust=-0.5,size = 8)+
  labs(title= " ", col ="", y="Frequency\n[Hz]", x = "Rotor speed\n[RPM]") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill="white", linetype = "solid"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 1 , linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "dark gray"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.5, linetype = 'solid',
                                        colour = "gray"))+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", text = element_text(size=40), legend.text=element_text(size=50))+
  guides(col = guide_legend(ncol = 3))
```

[image: Campbell diagram]

Comment: Instead of sharing data frames like this please consider using ```dput()```. You can just use ```dput(df_Pmodes)``` and copy-paste the result here. And then for the other one. In this way, it will be easier for others to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Updated with @Shibaprasad's comment